# Show Non-NULL values from 2 columns in a single column

Tags: sql-server

I need to take the non-null values from two columns and show in a new column:  ‘D_Country’.

1. C_Country(Customer)
2. P_Country(Prospect)

Each of these columns may have NULL values depending on who the quote was sent to (Customer or Prospect) but I want to display the actual country names in a new destination country column.  If C_Country is NULL then use P_Country or the reverse.

Comment: Are those in the same table or different tables?

Comment: different tables

Comment: You will want to use the [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function to return the first non-null value. At this point we'd be guessing on how you JOIN the tables to get the final result.  I'd suggest [editing](http://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/72758/edit) your question with more info like table structures - even your current query.

Comment: select 
 Co.orig_site,
 Co.slsman,
 Co.type,
 Co.stat,
 Co.cust_num,
 Co.co_num,
 Co.order_date,
 custaddr.country as C_Country,
 Co.prospect_id,
 prospect.country as P_Country,
 Co.Uf_QuoteType,
 Co.taken_by,
  Co.price AS UnconvertedPrice,
  Co.price / Co.exch_rate AS ConvertedPrice
 

from Co
 left outer join custaddr on Co.cust_num = custaddr.cust_num and Co.cust_seq = custaddr.cust_seq
 left outer join prospect on prospect.prospect_id = Co.prospect_id

Answer (score 1):

You can use ISNULL if there are only the two columns or COALESCE.  My personal preference is ISNULL but you can see the differences between the two here: http://sqlstudies.com/2013/08/07/how-are-coalesce-and-isnull-different/#comments

In your case it would look like this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(C_Country, P_Country) AS D_Country FROM TableName
```

This will return C_Country if it is non null or P_Country if C_Country is null.

Comment: No problem.  Mark the answer as correct if it covers your question.  Thanks :)